# Llamada a otro modulo en python

Tags: python

Tengo un script que llama a otro. El caso es que saber algunas alternativas a subprocess. Os dejo un ejemplo de lo que trato de realizar.

```
def abrirScript():
            subprocess.Popen(["python", "otromodulo.py"])
```

Comment: `import otromodulo` te lo ejecuta también. Depende de qué quieres hacer exactamente

Comment: A la hora de llamar a la función que abra el módulo. Y hacerlo de forma que al crear un ejecutable no de problemas.

Comment: Sale el siguiente error: python: can't open file 'C:\Users\...otromodulo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory